# Asking a good question about identity management

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Some of my questions were not accepted well; I'll try my luck with Meta first.

To formulate the topic/subject: given an auth API for user/group management: create users with passwords, add them to groups, like this.

On the other end there is KeyCloak which supports SAML.

My question is at best how I can formulate it: while I think whether it could be possible to implement some intermediate software/KeyCloak plugin to integrate with that auth API, I think the answer would be yes. (like, dynamic users during a session, simulate user login and pass a cookie, these are details)

However I am not sure *how to validate* this idea conceptually with some high chance of probability - is it possible without starting an actual trial and error project? From reading the docs of KeyCloak custom extensions I am not sure.

Not sure how better formulate this architecturing/design question and where to start in this specific SAML/IAM context.

Comment: that is it can't be that the community as whole has no experience about this specifc combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have questions about a specific product (KeyCloak). Such questions will not be received well on Softwareengineering.SE, because it is unlikely you will find many experts on this topic here. Fortunately, as with almost any Open Source technology, there is a place where you can find the experts - the **community forums of the product**, like the ones listed here:

https://www.keycloak.org/community

The kind of question which could fit somewhat better on Softwarengineering is, for example, how to generally validate the usage of a new technology before setting up a prototype, but beware - such questions are likely become too broad for the Q&A format of this site, and would most probably be closed as "needs more focus". Such questions need to be strictly narrowed down by stating requirements, restrictions and context.

Moreover, from a software engineers point of view, building a prototype is de facto **the** standard approach for validating a new technology or concept - so when you ask how you can avoid this step, don't be astonished the only answer you will get is  - "don't".

Comment: I's expect that sometimes also software engineers make sort of analysis/concept

Comment: @J.Doe: your question was not how to make a concept, but how to *validate* a concept. Software engineers validate a concept the same way scientists validate a theory - by trying it out and making experiments.